# Applet ClassDeffNotFound error if called from HTML outside the applet folder

Tags: java, html, web, applet

Whenever I run my applet, I get the error `ClassDeffNotFound` or something like that. There is no error is in the code, code is fine. Issue is with how I called to the applet using HTML. I am using the following:

```
<applet code="Form.class" width="486" height="712"></applet>
```

This is when the HTML file is directly inside the applet folder. The applet works 100% fine in this case

Now this one

```
<applet code="Calculator\src\Form.class" width="486" height="712">
```

This is when the HTML file is in the root folder. But this case, it is always giving `ClassDeffNotFound`!

My HTML file should be in the root folder while the applet should stay in folder dedicated to it. But, unless I place the HTML file inside the applet folder, it is errors.

Why is this?

Comment: Make sure your applet class and html file in same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the applet class is located in `Calculator\src` folder relative to the HTML file then the applet tag should include the `codebase` attribute:

```
<applet code="Form.class" codebase="Calculator/src" width="486" height="712">
```

Although it's very unlikely that the class file will be stored in the projects `src` folder. This is typically the `bin` folder.